# What is this shield? (AST Space Arduino Kit)

Tags: arduino-uno, shields

I recently got a box with Arduino components from someone who didn't want it (in part, because the manual was (probably) in Chinese). However, to my surprise, I could not find this kit on the internet. I would like to know: **is this a copy of another kit?**  Or, is there documentation available for this particular kit?

Box contents:

- Arduino Uno
- Unknow shield "by AST Space" with

  - AI-THINKER wi-fi module
  - Songle relais
  - YLB3641AH 4-digit LED display
  - DHT-11 relative humidity, temperature sensor
  - IR receivers, switches, microphone/buzzer, light sensor, connectors to the other components
- MPU6050 accelerometer
- HC-SR04 ultrasonic rangefinder
- QAPASS LCD unit
- "Car MP3" IR remote
- 2x green, 2x red LED, 5x resistor
- 17x10 green breadboard
- 2x DC motor, 1x geared stepper motor
- 40-wide female-female jumper ribbon cable
- USB connector cable (black)

It came in an intricate folding box, bright orange. The QR code links to http://weixin.qq.com/r/2kgtNVXEKwhUrRFW9x3I (which did not get me anywhere - visiting this link is at your own risk). Pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try scanning the QR code? I can't because your picture is too blurry.

Comment: @Majenko Yeah, it was a broken link; further inspection revealed it was a link to a sponsor. I checked the internet archives, but nowhere was any reference to anything related to this kit or Arduino in general.

Comment: It looks like "AST Space" is the online name of a Chinese blogger...

Comment: You could just backwards engineer the shield.  Other than what appears to be a WIFI at the top and, maybe, a bluetooth at the bottom - everything else appears to be simply hanging off the Arduino Uno's pins.  But it is hard to tell as the  picture is not all that clear. Guessing, there is no single point to this shield.  It is a collection of different devices. So other then for teaching, its use (mainly because it's huge) is rather limited.

Comment: @st2000 That's what I've been doing, but there's a few components whose function I don't know, and I am afraid I could miss a few things. I was mostly wondering whether this was a known board, but given these reactions, it's probably a one-off.

Comment: Looks like a great shield. Maybe something here https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.co.uk&sl=zh-CN&u=http://www.yiweibiying.com/p/J9MPkxx.html&usg=ALkJrhg47ONSQlf2deaRdrkbCgRtG6qgOA

Comment: Take a close up of the bits that are confusing you. There are plenty of people here who enjoy backwards engineering hardware.  Just try to ask one question per post.  Try to make it as specific as possible.  And alter your question in order to clear up any misunderstandings or to clarify the question.

Comment: @st2000 I will in due time. But, as for now, I was hoping to avoid having to ask various bits and pieces if there was a comprehensive overview for this particular shield. Thanks for your time, nevertheless!

Comment: There are no links that I can find to the PDF or the downloads or anything else anymore. I was given one of these kits at work and asked to look into it. Does Anyone have a working link to English Manual or link to the Download site above etc.. Thanks in Advance. Scott

Comment: @ScottPinard I made a rough translation of a PDF found in the RAR linked in dda's answer. I uploaded it here for you: https://we.tl/5j77KOe99E Feel free to upvote this question if you find it useful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My name is Bing Zhu. I the host of ASTSpace a community open lab sponsored by Zhejiang Association for Science and Technology(ZAST). AST is situated inside the Zhejiang Museum of Science and Technology. We are non-profit. The Kit you have gotten must be from someone got it free at one of ASTSpace's events. I remembered that we had brought some with us to the Manchester Science Festival where we did a tinkering activity for the public, 3 years ago.
This kit was designed by one of our members who is currently a Ph.D. student of automation at Zhejiang University. It was developed for the purpose to increase public experiences in a 90 minutes session. Therefore, in order to shorten the time of wiring while most times participants with no backgrounds or exposures to electronics make no sense anyway, we purposely had most of the functioning parts soldered on. In this way, we think it would be more manageable as well for teaching as most times one instructor has to manage more than a room full of over 25 participants. Making sure that parts are connected and in place can be a life-saver. We had it designed this way so the kit can be used in classes by schools in remote areas. These kits are given away and the introduction sessions are free to the public, and we intended to provide online help to those who decide to venture on with this kit at their own time. But, it never took off for time and resource restriction.  With this kit we have gone through two major cities in the Zhejiang Province and 4 remote rural areas. 
All our expenses are supported by ZAST through two projects, one to make it and one to distribute it. When we did what we did, it was always for the public to know electronic control and coding was made easy by Arduino where it was first invented by an Italian who wanted to teach artists electronics. 
This kit was used to demo how easily and readily everything can be controlled and through these electronics, we can take the parts of the physical world into our hands to follow our wills. We did use it to demo the on and off lighting system of the entire science center and controls of a remote camera inside the security room.
So, ASTSpace Arduino kit is a tailor-made kit for a specific purpose. We did not change anything but redesigned the wiring of the sensors for easy use for our events.

Comment: Hi Bing, thanks for your answer. I indeed got it from a young student who attended one of your sessions. They gave it away due to a lack of skills and interest in programming (which can seem very daunting to novices). The board is now part of an Internet of Things project, and I'm planning to use some of the peripherals as a robotics demonstrator.

Answer (score 2):

AST stands for Art, Science and Technology. The learning kit is produced by [AST Space](https://translate.google.com/translate?depth=1&hl=en&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.co.uk&sl=zh-CN&u=http://www.yiweibiying.com/p/J9MPkxx.html) who also run maker competitions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm Xiaotian, the designer of this arduino learning Kit. We designed that for people who love DIY but without electronic backgrounds. In the past events, we found everybody (12-16 year old kids usually) could start wiring and coding and finish a little projects with the kit and its examples in 90 mins. All of hardware and software are modular, you could assembly them you want and make your great ideas real quickly.
If you want to know more details about it, feel free to let me know. My email is xtchen@zju.edu.cn.
Thanks for your attention!

Xiaotian

Answer (score 1):

On http://astspace.org/ you can download a PDF related to this [AST Space Kit](http://ast-space.b0.upaiyun.com/AST%20Arduino%20Kit%E8%B5%84%E6%96%99%E5%8C%85.rar)[rar archive].

[image: Shield Description]

I took the schema in the PDF and translated in English. Looking at the examples (see below), it looks like the "Wifi Module" is an ESP8266.

The QR code in the PDF is actually readable, but you have to scan it in WeChat (a social platform that mixes chat, Instagram and shopping).

The QR code links to AST Space's account:

[image]

The download mentioned above contains schematics and sample code. Download that and you should have a much better understanding on how to use it.

[image]